# Is there an efficient way to delete the duplicated block with same start and end to keep unique?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, functions, sort

#### Description

I have many large size files may including the same function definition.
The block description is start with `.start .*` and end with `.end`
In this example there is one duplicate definition `.start aa aa`
My purpose is to make the duplicated description unique.
BTW, I am using Windows Vim, there's no Linux command `uniq` to use.

```
.start aa aa
aaaaa
bbbbb
.end

.start bb cc
aaaaa
bbbbb
.end

.start aa aa                   <---- duplicated description from here
aaaaa
bbbbb                       
.end                           <---- to there
```

My traditional solution is:

1. Find the every block and replace the `\n` to `\t` as a marker in order to make them into one line
   `:g/\v\.start/,/\.end/s/\n/\t/g`
2. Sort the line and remove the duplicated keep unique `:sort u`
3. Finally replace the marker `\t` to `\n` make the line back to original block style `:g/\v^\.start.*end/s/\t/\r/g`

#### Question

Refer to these two answers
[How can I sort multiline blocks in vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25042/how-can-i-sort-multiline-blocks-in-vim)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46660252/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-groups-of-lines-in-vim/46660877#46660877
I found a helpful and easy way to sort the block by group or by header

So is there a more efficient way than my traditional solution to keep the same definition block unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some details of your implementation could be improved but the general strategy is sound.

```
:g/\.start/,/\.end/s/\n/\t
:sort u
:g/\.start/s/\t/\r/g
```

- No need for `\v`.
- Some patterns can be simplified.
- No need for `/g` on the first command since there is only one `\n` per line.

The first command *may* also be simplified to:

```
:g/\.start/,'}-s/\n/\t
```

See `:help '}`.

Note that `:sort u` kind of implies that you only have those blocks in the buffer, which may or may not open the door to undesired side-effects if that's not the case (losing single line comments, messing with multiline comments, etc.).

If that's too much work, several plugin-based solutions have been suggested in the linked Q/As.

Comment: Where'e the linked Q/As?

Comment: In… your question?

Comment: lol, I misunderstand.